# Why is "this" null, in the link function within an Angular Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-directive

I'm trying to write a dynamic template using TypeScript and Angular, however for some reason the 'this' keyword is always null, thus I cannot access my private member $compile. Any ideas? Many Thanks! :-)

Directive:

```
namespace ROD.Features.Player {
    "use strict";

    export class VideoDirective implements ng.IDirective {
        public restrict: string = "E";
        public replace: boolean = true;
        public scope = {
            content: "="
        };

        constructor(private $compile: ng.ICompileService) {
        }

        public link(element: JQuery, scope: ng.IScope): any {
            const youtubeTemplate = "<p>Youtube</p>";
            const vimeoTemplate = "<p>Vimeo</p>";

            var linkFn = this.$compile(youtubeTemplate);
            const content: any = linkFn(scope);
            element.append(content);
        }
    }
}
```

App.ts:

```
namespace ROD {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("rodApp", [])
        .service("Settings", [() => new Settings.DevelopmentSettings()])
        .service("RedditService", [
            "$http", "Settings",
            ($http: ng.IHttpService, settings: Settings.ISettings) => new Services.Reddit.RedditService($http, settings.sourceUrl),
        ])
        .directive("videoItem", ["$compile",
            ($compile: ng.ICompileService) => new Features.Player.VideoDirective($compile)])
        .controller("PlayerController", [
            "$scope", "RedditService",
            ($scope: any, redditService: Services.Reddit.IRedditService) => new Features.Player.PlayerController($scope, redditService),
        ]);
}
```

Comment: I don't see a reference to the `this` keyword anywhere in your code - am I misunderstanding something? How/were are you trying to reference `this`?

Comment: can you transcompile this to plain javascript for us?

Comment: could you post the error you are getting?

Comment: Apologies, it was quite late.. I pasted the wrong code. You can see I use the this keyword in the directive. Please see above, many thanks.

Comment: @HenryZou: Here is the plain javascript (line 66): https://github.com/AdrianLThomas/ROD/blob/dc23ea53f6a15f5ca4e89577c4c8aca43e35b1f9/sln/ROD.Web/wwwroot/js/app.js#L66

Comment: it could be possible that the arrow function you use in app.ts to define the directive makes it so this is not properly bound in the directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that I was using the wrong syntax for the link function. This is the correct implementation:

```
        public link = (element: JQuery, scope: ng.IScope): any => {
            const youtubeTemplate = "<p>Youtube</p>";
            const vimeoTemplate = "<p>Vimeo</p>";

            var linkFn = this.$compile(youtubeTemplate);
            const content: any = linkFn(scope);
            element.append(content);
        }
```

Can anyone explain why this is? :-)

Comment: ES6 arrow functions preserve lexical context for `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

You need to have:

```
    .directive("videoItem", ["$compile",
    function ($compile) { return () => new ROD.Features.Player.VideoDirective($compile); }])
```

instead of

```
    .directive("videoItem", ["$compile",
    function ($compile) { return new ROD.Features.Player.VideoDirective($compile); }])
```

in your `app.js`. An explanation of the problem is here: http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/350/exploring-es6-classes-in-angularjs-1-x#_section-directives The gist of the problem is that when angular calls `link` function, the context of this is not preserved.

If you want to understand the issue more in-depth, just use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js` and have a look what the call stack looks like.

Comment: Thanks. What your saying makes sense - though it doesn't appear to work as the link function doesn't get called any more. Can't see any errors in the console either..