# "this" undefined in side link function in Angular directive built with TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm a relative newbie to both TypeScript and Angular so I'm probably doing something very basic wrong here.

I'm trying to create an abstract base class from which I can derive multiple directives, each of which will implement a single custom validation rule. My code compiles okay, but fails at runtime, specifically when it tries to call this.isValid(...) because "this" is undefined at that point. Can anyone see what is wrong with this code?

```
module App.Common.Directives {
    'use strict';

    export abstract class ValidatorBase implements angular.IDirective {

        require = 'ng-model';
        restrict = 'A';

        constructor(private validationErrorKey: string) { }

        link(scope: angular.IScope, el: angular.IAugmentedJQuery, attributes: Directives.IValidatorAttributes, controller: angular.IFormController) {
            //tsc writes "var _this = this;" here, but this is undefined
            scope.$watch(attributes.ngModel, () => {
                const val: string = el.val();
                const valid = this.isValid(val, el, scope, attributes, controller);
                controller.$setValidity(this.validationErrorKey, valid, undefined);
            });
        }

        abstract isValid(val: any, el?: angular.IAugmentedJQuery, scope?: angular.IScope, attributes?: Directives.IValidatorAttributes, controller?: angular.IFormController): boolean;

    }
}
```

Here is the output from the TypeScript compiler for this class:

```
var App;
(function (App) {
    var Common;
    (function (Common) {
        var Directives;
        (function (Directives) {
            'use strict';
            var ValidatorBase = (function () {
                function ValidatorBase(validationErrorKey) {
                    this.validationErrorKey = validationErrorKey;
                    this.require = 'ng-model';
                    this.restrict = 'A';
                }
                ValidatorBase.prototype.link = function (scope, el, attributes, controller) {
                    var _this = this; //this is undefined when we get here
                    scope.$watch(attributes.ngModel, function () {
                        var val = el.val();
                        var valid = _this.isValid(val, el, scope, attributes, controller);
                        controller.$setValidity(_this.validationErrorKey, valid, undefined);
                    });
                };
                return ValidatorBase;
            })();
            Directives.ValidatorBase = ValidatorBase;
        })(Directives = Common.Directives || (Common.Directives = {}));
    })(Common = App.Common || (App.Common = {}));
})(App || (App = {}));
```

Comment: Seems like I have exactly duplicated this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561415/why-is-this-null-in-the-link-function-within-an-angular-directive - just going to try that solution now.

Comment: Changing the syntax of the link method in TypeScript as per the other question worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angular directives it is unsafe to consider `this` a class instance because functions can have their own lexical `this`, and they actually have it.

`this` is controller instance in `controller` (which may or may not be exposed on scope with 'controller as' syntax).

`this` is DDO object in `compile` (so `this` is contextual here).

`this` is `undefined` in linking functions (in strict mode).

Use arrow functions if you're unsure about lexical `this` or want to override it:

```
link = (...) => { ... };
```

Comment: Thanks for this, great explanation. The solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561415/why-is-this-null-in-the-link-function-within-an-angular-directive works, but now I understand why it works.

Answer (score 0):

> //tsc writes "var _this = this;" here, but this is undefined

Two possible issues:

- You should type `_this` in the debug console. This is because of the way the sourcemaps work at the moment : [Chrome Typescript debugging references wrong 'this'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346989/chrome-typescript-debugging-references-wrong-this/31351458#31351458)
- You are registering the directive with angular in a wrong way. Note that angular will not call *new* on `foo` if foo is used like `.directive('foo',foo)`. Angular assumes its already a variable that has all the right stuff on it. Angular was not written with classes in mind (angular 1 is now fairly old).