# keyword 'this' in angular directives

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I'm creating an Directive to display Google Maps API.

**Directive:**

```
.directive('googleMaps', ["$cordovaGeolocation", function($cordovaGeolocation){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            var options = {
                timeout: 10000,
                enableHighAccuracy: true
            };

            $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){
                var latitude = position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude = position.coords.longitude;

                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                var mapOptions = {
                    center: latLng,
                    zoom: 15,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(this, mapOptions);
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Following very simple tutorials (the main one being [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map)) I have created it.
In the `google.maps.Map(...)` method, you'll notice it accepts 2 params.
On the tutorial, that is the HTML element which you position the map on.
I thought, since using a directive and `restrict: 'E'` that I could just pass `this` as that param.
So my questions are:

- Am I correct in thinking that way?
- Is there another way to do it? *(I know of `document.getElementById("google-maps")`)*
- What does `this` actually refer to in Angular directives?

**Note:** When debugging, `this` returns an instance of `Window`

**EDIT:** Have tried `document.getElementsByTagName("google-maps")` and that is not even working

Comment: As ``this`` has no execution context defined, it will be ``window`` in the browser. Replace ``this`` with ``element[0]``. More on ``this`` scoping - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this and the Google Maps docs which says that ``google.maps.Map`` constructor takes HTML Element object - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["this" undefined in side link function in Angular directive built with TypeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911206/this-undefined-in-side-link-function-in-angular-directive-built-with-typescrip)

Comment: why re-invent the wheel when theree are several different google map angular modules already available and documented as well as with examples

Comment: @charlietfl I have considered them, however, I did not write the original code and am just merely doing a code review with a few tweaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `google.maps.Map constructor` expects a HTML element (*div container*) map object could be instantiated in `link` function via `element` parameter:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(element[0]);
```

where `element[0]` refers to current HTML element (`element` in link function is represented as [jQlite object](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element))

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('map', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                'options' : '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
               
                var map = new google.maps.Map(element[0]);
                if (scope.options){
                   map.setOptions(scope.options);   
                }
        
            }
        };
    })
    .controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {

    });
```

```css
#map_div {
        height: 400px;
        width: 660px;
        position:absolute;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<div ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <map id="map_div" zoom="12" options="{zoom: 10, center:{lat:59.9171469,lng:30.0442039}}"></map>
</div>
```

or via `attrs` parameter, for example:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(attrs.id));
```

where `attrs.id` refers to current element id

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('map', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                'options' : '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(attrs.id));
                if (scope.options){
                   map.setOptions(scope.options);   
                }
        
            }
        };
    })
    .controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {

    });
```

```css
#map_div {
        height: 400px;
        width: 660px;
        position:absolute;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<div ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <map id="map_div" zoom="12" options="{zoom: 10, center:{lat:59.9171469,lng:30.0442039}}"></map>
</div>
```