# Angular $interval is not a function issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, clock

I know that probably you will mark this as a duplicate but none of sibling topics doesn't solve my problem, so this is my simple date count down directive:

```
class Clock {
    constructor() {
        this.restrict = 'AC';
        this.replace = true;
        this.template = require('./templates/clock.tpl.html');
        this.scope = {};
    }
    link(scope, elem, attrs, $interval) {
        let end = new Date('05/05/2017 9:00 AM');

        let _second = 1000;
        let _minute = _second * 60;
        let _hour = _minute * 60;
        let _day = _hour * 24;

        scope.showRemaining = () => {
            let now = new Date();
            let distance = end - now;
            let days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
            let hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
            let minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
            let seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

            scope.days = days;
            scope.hours = hours;
            scope.minutes = minutes;
            scope.seconds = seconds;
        }

        $interval(showRemaining, 1000;)
    }
}

// create factory function to handle DI
function factory() {
    "ngInject";

    return new Clock();
}

export default factory;
```

I've bean searching the cause of this issue and everywhere i reach info that the interval function must be passed as a normal one without parameters or any other addons. But still i have the same error, which is:

`TypeError: $interval is not a function`

Can anybody help?

Comment: Inject it via the controller, not the link function

Answer (score 5):

You have to inject dependencies in your constructor, not in the `link` function:

```
constructor($interval) {
    // ..
    this.$interval = $interval;
}
link(scope, elem, attrs) {
    // ..
    this.$interval(showRemaining, 1000;)
}
```

Comment: upvoted, though I don't think he's writting in typescript

Comment: yeap, this is not a typescript

Comment: You of course also have to pass it to the constructor in your factory function

Comment: It won't work. `link` function in directives (and the class above is a constructor for DDO object) doesn't have `this`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using classes for constructing directive objects is that directive functions have non-lexical `this` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34925017/3731501) for more details). It is possible to inject `$interval` to the constructor, but using it from `link` function isn't possible without binding it:

```
constructor($interval) {
  ...
  this.$interval = $interval;
  this.link = this.link.bind(this);
}
```

This indicates a design problem. Directives aren't suited for classes. Using them to construct directive objects doesn't have benefits. These classes aren't reusable. They don't have architectural advantages.

Angular 1.5+ borrows ideas from Angular 2 (making the migration easier is one of the tasks for current releases) and makes the development controller-centric. This resulted in replacing pre-link and post-link functions with `$onInit` and `$postLink` hooks.

The practical approach to class-based AngularJS development may look like:

```
class ClockController {
  constructor($interval) {
    this.$interval = $interval;
  }

  $onInit() {
    this.$interval(() => this.showRemaining(), 1000);
  }

  showRemaining() { ... }
}

app.directive('clock', () => ({
  ...
  controller: ClockController
}));
```

It makes sense to convert this directive into a component at this point, because this is what components are doing. They are basically wrappers for directives that force controller-centric approach.